Sharing a single tab in Google sheet as a viewr?
Is it possible to share a single tab in Google sheet without being able to view other tabs?

It's not possible to share a single tab. If you are fine with users getting view-only access, you may want to explore Looker Studio. See the Gallery for examples of what you can do with it.
In the previous question you asked about using importrange() for this. When users have edit access to the "viewing" sheet, they can insert additional importrange() formulas to "peek around" the source spreadsheet, which means that a determined can user discover all of the original data. Note that that is not an issue with viewers because they cannot add formulas.
You can also use a view-only middleman spreadsheet to make the viewing spreadsheet bulletproof. The middleman spreadsheet prevents the  use of importrange() to "peek around" — all that can be discovered is the data in the middleman. The source spreadsheet does not need to be shared with anyone. You do not need to grant the viewers any rights to the source spreadsheet or the middleman spreadsheet — they only need to be able to view the viewing spreadsheet.
